Issues following apt upgrade
I've got a situation that has come about just yesterday after an apt full-upgrade. It seems the apps that are affected are apps that I had previously installed from debian-backports. Here's the rundown with all the history I could muster:
1. Modify /etc/apt/sources.list to add bookworm-backports; o/a 15 Aug 2024:
About 2.5 months ago, I concluded that I needed the backports versions of pipewire and wireplumber.  To make this happen, I modified my /etc/apt/sources.list file to add backports:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
# Uncomment deb-src lines below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports main contrib non-free

No changes were made to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main

2. Install pipewire et. al. from bookworm-backports; o/a 15 Aug 2024:
$ sudo apt install -t bookworm-backports pipewire pipewire-audio-client-libraries libspa-0.2-bluetooth 
...
$ sudo reboot


Afterwards, the pipewire & wireplumber versions (from backports) installed on my system were:
$ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 1.2.1
Linked with libpipewire 1.2.1 

$ wireplumber --version
wireplumber
Compiled with libwireplumber 0.4.17
Linked with libwireplumber 0.4.17

3. Fast forward to 9 Oct, 2024 after completion of testing
This system had not been upgraded in two months as I was running a test on the apps that I'm now having trouble with. Here's what I saw yesterday:
Note bookworm-backports in the list below:
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports InRelease [59.0 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease [39.0 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main armhf Packages [181 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main arm64 Packages [185 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main Translation-en [114 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main arm64 Packages [249 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main armhf Packages [250 kB]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main Translation-en [210 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/contrib arm64 Packages [4,964 B]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/contrib armhf Packages [4,740 B]
Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/non-free arm64 Packages [6,864 B]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/non-free armhf Packages [1,516 B]
Get:16 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [515 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [485 kB]
Fetched 2,409 kB in 4s (614 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
59 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

I've marked (*) the 12 entries that are coming from backports:
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
base-files/stable 12.4+deb12u7 arm64 [upgradable from: 12.4+deb12u6]
curl/stable 7.88.1-10+deb12u7 arm64 [upgradable from: 7.88.1-10+deb12u6]
git-man/stable-security,stable-security 1:2.39.5-0+deb12u1 all [upgradable from: 1:2.39.2-1.1]
git/stable-security 1:2.39.5-0+deb12u1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1:2.39.2-1.1]
initramfs-tools-core/stable,stable 0.142+deb12u1 all [upgradable from: 0.142]
initramfs-tools/stable,stable 0.142+deb12u1 all [upgradable from: 0.142]
libc-bin/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc-dev-bin/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc-devtools/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc-l10n/stable,stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 all [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc6-dbg/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc6-dev/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libc6/stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
libcamera-ipa/stable 0.3.2+rpt20240927-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 0.3.0+rpt20240617-1]
libcamera0.3/stable 0.3.2+rpt20240927-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 0.3.0+rpt20240617-1]
libcurl3-gnutls/stable 7.88.1-10+deb12u7 arm64 [upgradable from: 7.88.1-10+deb12u6]
libcurl4/stable 7.88.1-10+deb12u7 arm64 [upgradable from: 7.88.1-10+deb12u6]
libexpat1/stable-security 2.5.0-1+deb12u1 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.5.0-1]
libpam-systemd/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
* libpipewire-0.3-0/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* libpipewire-0.3-common/stable-backports,stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 all [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* libpipewire-0.3-modules/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
libpisp-common/stable,stable 1.0.7-1 all [upgradable from: 1.0.6-1]
libpisp1/stable 1.0.7-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.0.6-1]
* libspa-0.2-bluetooth/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* libspa-0.2-modules/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
libssl3/stable 3.0.14-1~deb12u2+rpt1 arm64 [upgradable from: 3.0.13-1~deb12u1+rpt1]
libsystemd-shared/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
libsystemd0/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
libudev1/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
linux-headers-rpi-2712/stable 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 arm64 [upgradable from: 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1]
linux-headers-rpi-v8/stable 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 arm64 [upgradable from: 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1]
linux-image-rpi-2712/stable 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 arm64 [upgradable from: 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1]
linux-image-rpi-v8/stable 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 arm64 [upgradable from: 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1]
linux-libc-dev/stable,stable 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 all [upgradable from: 1:6.6.31-1+rpt1]
locales/stable,stable 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u8 all [upgradable from: 2.36-9+rpt2+deb12u7]
openssl/stable 3.0.14-1~deb12u2+rpt1 arm64 [upgradable from: 3.0.13-1~deb12u1+rpt1]
* pipewire-alsa/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* pipewire-audio-client-libraries/stable-backports,stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 all [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* pipewire-bin/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* pipewire-jack/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* pipewire-pulse/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
* pipewire/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
python3-gpiozero/stable,stable 2.0.1-0+rpt1 all [upgradable from: 2.0-1]
raspberrypi-sys-mods/stable 20240911 arm64 [upgradable from: 20240807]
raspi-firmware/stable,stable 1:1.20240924-1 all [upgradable from: 1:1.20240529-1]
raspi-utils-core/stable 20240903-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
raspi-utils-dt/stable 20240903-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
raspi-utils-eeprom/stable 20240903-1 arm64 [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
raspi-utils-otp/stable,stable 20240903-1 all [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
raspi-utils/stable,stable 20240903-1 all [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
raspinfo/stable,stable 20240903-1 all [upgradable from: 20240402-4]
rpi-eeprom/stable,stable 26.0-1 all [upgradable from: 24.0-1]
rpicam-apps-lite/stable 1.5.2-2 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.5.0-2]
systemd-sysv/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
systemd-timesyncd/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
systemd/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
udev/stable 252.30-1~deb12u2 arm64 [upgradable from: 252.26-1~deb12u2]
* wireplumber/stable-backports 0.5.6-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 0.4.17-1~bpo12+1]

And so I did an upgrade on the entire list; this appeared to complete normally, but some items escaped my attention (not watching the screen during the upgrade) until the "wheels came off":
$ sudo apt -y full-upgrade
...

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libwireplumber-0.4-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwireplumber-0.5-0 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-common-rpi linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 linux-headers-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8
  linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 linux-image-6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v8 linux-kbuild-6.6.51+rpt
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files curl git git-man initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev
  libcamera-ipa libcamera0.3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libexpat1 libpam-systemd libpipewire-0.3-0 libpipewire-0.3-common libpipewire-0.3-modules
  libpisp-common libpisp1 libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-modules libssl3 libsystemd-shared libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-headers-rpi-2712
  linux-headers-rpi-v8 linux-image-rpi-2712 linux-image-rpi-v8 linux-libc-dev locales openssl pipewire pipewire-alsa
  pipewire-audio-client-libraries pipewire-bin pipewire-jack pipewire-pulse python3-gpiozero raspberrypi-sys-mods raspi-firmware raspi-utils
  raspi-utils-core raspi-utils-dt raspi-utils-eeprom raspi-utils-otp raspinfo rpi-eeprom rpicam-apps-lite systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  udev wireplumber
59 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

...

apt-listchanges: Reading changelogs...
apt-listchanges: News
---------------------

wireplumber (0.5.1-1) experimental; urgency=medium

  WirePlumber 0.5 was released with a new configuration system.
  The new system is based on JSON instead of Lua which makes WirePlumber >= 0.5
  incompatible with Lua conf files written for WirePlumber 0.4.
  .
  If only the default configuration (e.g the configuration shipped with the
  Debian package) is used, then there is nothing to do.
  .
  If you use custom configuration files, you will have to manually update them
  by following the migration guide. No automatic migration of old configuration
  files is performed.
  .
  This guide is available at (after having installed "wireplumber-doc"):
    /usr/share/doc/wireplumber/html/daemon/configuration/migration.html
  or
    https://pipewire.pages.freedesktop.org/wireplumber/daemon/configuration/migration.html

 -- Dylan Aïssi <daissi@debian.org>  Sun, 31 Mar 2024 14:44:46 +0200

...

$ sudo reboot
... 


4. After the upgrade I discover "the wheels have come off"; pipewire no longer works at all; no Bluetooth sound!
Just to confirm what I could already tell, I checked Bluetooth status w/ systemctl
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-10-09 22:29:30 UTC; 1h 6min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 507 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 404)
        CPU: 196ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─507 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: Starting SDP server
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: profiles/audio/vcp.c:vcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init vcp plugin
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: profiles/audio/mcp.c:mcp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init mcp plugin
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: profiles/audio/bap.c:bap_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() Failed to init bap plugin
Oct 09 22:29:30 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Oct 09 22:29:31 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
Oct 09 22:29:31 rpi2w bluetoothd[507]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)

$

bluetoothctl was able to connect with my speaker, but nothing - no sound.
5. Restore system from raw image file created o/a 16 Aug 2024
This "brought my system back" to the same state it was immediately after installing pipewire et. al. (when it worked well!). So - I have a fully functional system again at this point; 9 Oct, 2024.
6. Begin incremental upgrades; 9 Oct, 2024
Through a process of trial-and-error, I began an "incremental" upgrade, using sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade X Y Z etc. After each upgrade I checked that Bluetooth was still working. After I whittled the list of un-installed packages down to the following, Bluetooth was still working:
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done

libpipewire-0.3-common/stable-backports,stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 all [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
libpipewire-0.3-modules/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
libspa-0.2-bluetooth/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
libspa-0.2-modules/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire-alsa/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire-audio-client-libraries/stable-backports,stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 all [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire-bin/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire-jack/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire-pulse/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
pipewire/stable-backports 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 1.2.1-1~bpo12+1]
wireplumber/stable-backports 0.5.6-1~bpo12+1 arm64 [upgradable from: 0.4.17-1~bpo12+1]

7. pipewire et. al. are apparently solely responsible for the Bluetooth malfunction. I guess this may be "no surprise" to many, but I felt I needed to establish as specifically as possible the source of the problem.
Here's my question: How did I screw this up? I've never used backports previously, and I assumed that when the regular channel "caught up" with backports that apt would see that everything was merged/installed without incident. Obviously, that's not what happened here. What do I need to do to fix this?

You didn’t screw this up, and your assumptions are correct.
Given that you currently have a working system, there are two ways to avoid upgrading the backported packages:

You can disable the bookworm-backports repository entirely — this will prevent upgrades to pipewire & co., but will also prevent installing any other backported package (which may be desirable in your case).

You can hold the currently-installed packages:
sudo apt-mark hold libpipewire-0.3-{common,modules} libspa-0.2-{bluetooth,modules} pipewire-{alsa,audio-client-libraries,bin,hack,pulse} pipewire wireplumber

This will keep those packages at their current versions regardless of which repositories are available.


Backports work as follows (by default, all this can be adjusted using pin priorities):

backported packages are never automatic candidates for installation or for upgrade from the current release version (that is to say, the release you’re tracking)
once installed (with an explicit -t bookworm-backports or other version specifier), backported packages are automatic candidates for upgrades to themselves, as long as the release version doesn’t catch up
non-sloppy backports are never allowed to overtake the next release

Because backports complement a given release, and package versions aren’t supposed to change significantly in a given release (other than a few exceptions such as browsers), a release will never catch up with backports. This means that once you install a backport, you’ll stay on backports for that package until you upgrade to the next major release — in this instance, Debian 13.
With all that said, what happened in this instance is that updated backports was released after your tests, culminating in pipewire 1.2.4-1~bpo12+1 and wireplumber 0.5.6-1~bpo12+1. The latter includes a news item, which you saw, added in 0.5.1-1 which was uploaded to experimental; as a result the news displayed is confusing — the package you got is a legitimate backport package, not an experimental one.
What this boils down to is unfortunately running into bugs. That’s the compromise with backports — you get updated packages, but they’re not as well-tested as those in the main release, or even as the same packages in unstable or testing. In particular, they may embed assumptions about other parts of the ecosystem — for example, a package can run fine with the other packages it relies on as they exist in unstable or testing, without the package maintainer realising that there’s a dependency on a feature only available in unstable or testing; the package may then build fine for backports, but fail (even partially) in its new transplanted environment. If you can be bothered it would be worth reporting a bug!

That's a lot to digest! What I'm interested in is a collection of packages that actually works. IIUYC, what's screwing me up is the wireplumber package. What I'm not sure of is how best to get rid of that! Can I remove the backports line from sources.list, and do another upgrade???  ... would that do it?

OK - that seems to have worked: I removed the backport source from /etc/apt/sources.list, re-ran update and then did a "normal" full-upgrade. Removing backports apparently caused the wireplumber update to disappear from the --upgradable list.

That will keep the wireplumber package at its current version, which is probably what you want. You could also hold the package, instead of disabling the backports repository entirely; see my updated answer.
